# Does Python "cache" functions?

Tags: python, function, caching

The title might be a bit misleading but I couldn't find a good way to express myself. Essentially if I had code like this:

```
def test_function(inputs):
    parameters = non_trivial_manipulation(inputs)
    return lambda x: some_function(parameters, x)

test = test_function(inputs)
```

My question is, does it go through all the manipulations in `test_function` every time I use `test`, or does Python somehow "cache" this so that the above code is actually efficient? If the latter, how does it do that?

Thanks!

Comment: When you call `test`, it only calls `lambda x: some_function(parameters, x)`, not `parameters = non_trivial_manipulation(inputs)`.

Answer (score -3):

It isn't Python, it's the OS that caches it. The more you repeat something, the more cache the OS writes.

Comment: Because it's hardly clear what "OS caching" you're referring to, so it's likely wrong, *and* it's probably not the kind of caching OP is referring to either.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-caching-in-an-operating-system
It's the first result from Google.